# Converting a truncated normal random variable to a uniform

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, transformation

This can be assumed as a follow-up question for [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343952/how-to-transform-gaussiannormal-distribution-to-uniform-distribution/2344086).

> Assume that $X$ is a truncated Gaussian random variable on range $[a,b]$, $E[X]=\mu$ and $Var(X)=\sigma^2$. Find a function of $X$ that converts it to a uniform random variable on the range $[l,u]$.

I have been working on the problem but could not find the solution. I believe we can use the same techniques as those used for [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343952/how-to-transform-gaussiannormal-distribution-to-uniform-distribution/2344086). So, we should use the CDF of the truncated normal variable which is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution). I don't know how to use it though.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ denote the CDF of $X$. Then the random variable $Y = F(X)$ is standard uniform. After all,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(Y \leq y) &= P(F(X) \leq y) \\
&= P(X \leq F^{-1}(y)) \\
&= F(F^{-1}(y)) \\
&= y
\end{split}
\end{equation}
for all $y \in [0, 1]$. So your desired function is just the CDF of the truncated normal distribution. Unfortunately, this cannot be written in closed form.